# Datatable gets destroyed after when redirecting to same page

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

i have a selectbox, on selection of option of this box datatable gets populated.

this table displays all the information of selected option in select box.

```
<select name="status" id="status" onchange="changeassigned()">
    <option>-- Select Status --</option>
    <option value="1">New</option>
    <option value="2">Inprogress</option>
    <option value="3">Completed</option>
    <option value="4">Rejected</option>
</select>
```

my ajax code to pass data to controller:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#querymasterdata').DataTable();
    });
<script>

function changeassigned()
    {
        var status_id = $('#status').val();
        var id = $('#assigned_to').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {id:id},
            url: "{{ URL::to('admin/poststatusid/') }}?status_id=" + status_id,
            success: function (data) {
                $('tbody').html(data.res);
            }
        });
    }
```

my rows of datatable is a link tag, when i click i am redirected to new page.

my problem is when i come back to same page my datatable is lost.

what is the reason for this..??

Comment: This is because you are loading data table values on ajax which isn't available on page load.

Comment: Problem i see in your code is , you are not redirecting your page ,instead you are putting the ajax return code to "<tbody>" of your dataTable.
this line of code is having problem 
       `$('tbody').html(data.res);`

Comment: I think the best way is to use the `ajax` option within DataTables itself rather than a separate ajax request, docs are here: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html